# Unable to install older version of scriptsharp

Tags: script#

I am having the hardest time setting up script#. I am needing it for a platform at work that requires I specifically use version 0.7.2.

I was able to get the older version from GitHub and can build it. However, I'm lost on where the project templates went. All of the old documentation says I should have access to a project template called Script# Class Library.

I've even tried installing the more recent versions, which I can install but the class templates no longer include the class library I need.

Answer (score 0):

Moved to a newer version.

I was able to resolve the main build issue with the old one by having CoreLib target the 2.0 network.